# Possible to annotate just one model in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Working with a large code base and I'm hesitant to run annotate on all models. Is it possible to use the Rails annotate plugin to just annotate one model at a time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm looking at the annotate 2.0.0 source and the only options to the rake task are some basic switches.  It does not accept any other arguments or switches.  I would guess that you're out of luck for the old-fashioned way.

It's a really simple gem.  You could always make the modification yourself and submit it back to the project.  Open source has its advantages.  =]

Comment: It's not hard to make a config/initializer monkeypatch that adds the functionality you want. That's a good compromise between forking and submitting a patch.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin itself is really trivial, about 50 lines of code:
http://repo.pragprog.com/svn/Public/plugins/annotate_models/lib/annotate_models.rb

You can easily adjust `do_annotations` method to read input parameter (or, maybe, just hardcode your model name in there).

But no, I don't see model-selection functionality in there right now.